# Using geocoder only in development or production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-geocoder, test-environments

I use the geocoder gem in my app, and when I run my tests, I meet the limit query error from Google. So I don't want to use it when I'm in a test environment, and I want some of my pages not to display some information when I'm in test, in order not to use the geocoder utility.

I tried this but it didn't worked, can you help me ?

**app/models/location.rb**

```rb
after_validation :geocode, if: :address_changed? && (Rails.env.production? || Rails.env.development? )
```

And

**app/helpers/location.rb** used in the **app/views/products/index.html.erb**

```rb
if Rails.env.test?
  t('location.distance.test')
else
  here.location.distance_to(there.location, :km)
end
```

That got me the following error message *for every test I run* :

```rb
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `after_validation' for false:FalseClass
```

And if I remove everything in my helper and the following code in my model, I have no more error.

```rb
&& (Rails.env.production? || Rails.env.development? )
```

Comment: In what way did it not work? Did you get an error or was the check ignored?

Comment: I got an error, because the method was unknown (I edited my post accordingly).

Comment: Flo, could you please post the full code that is throwing the error:
 -> the model (you can of course remove the methods not related to this issue)
 -> the method actually throwing the error: is it when you are trying to save a new instance ?
Thanks

Comment: Nico, I'm sure that's my syntax that is incorrect, because when I remove the checkings `Rails.env.production?` and `Rails.env.development?`, it works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write it like that:

```
unless Rails.env.test?
  after_validation :geocode, if: :address_changed?
end
```

Comment: Wow I can not believe how much time this has shaved off my test suite. Thanks.

Comment: Or `after_validation :geocode, if: ->(obj) { !Rails.env.test? && obj.address_changed? }`